# Uploading a file to ownCloud through PHP and a HTML Form

Tags: php, curl, owncloud

I'm having some troubles trying to develop a webapp for uploading files to my owncloud server trough a form using PHP, I'm using curl to PUT a request through the webDav, so here's the code:

Index.php

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Theform is here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div align="center">
                <h1> File uploads with OwnCloud API</h1>
                <form method="post" action="uploader.php" name="fileuploader">
                    <label>Select a File to upload</label><br>
                    <input type="file" name="file"></input><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="upload file"></input>
                </form>
                <?php
                ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

uploader.php

```
<?php
    $request = curl_init('http://mydomain.cl/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Dev/');

    curl_setopt($request,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($request,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,'Authorization: Basic');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt(
        $request,
        CURLOPT_INFILE,
        array(
            'thefile'=>
                        '@'            .$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
                        . ';filename=' .$_FILES['file']['daName']
                        . ';type='     .$_FILES['file']['type']

        ));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_INFILE, $_FILES['file']);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($_FILES['file']));


    // output the response
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    echo curl_exec($request);

    // close the session
    curl_close($request);

?>
```

When I try to upload the file I get this response:

> Sabre\DAV\Exception\NotAuthenticated No 'Authorization: Basic' header
>   found. Either the client didn't send one, or the server is
>   mis-configured

But when I use the owncloud Client I can access to my files without problems.

EDIT: Corrected the name variable $ch to $request and added the line :

> curl_setopt($request,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,'Authorization: Basic');

from @Craig post, after that I got this error message:

> Sabre\DAV\Exception\Conflict PUT is not allowed on non-files.

Please help me to solve this. Regards :D

Comment: EDIT: Browsing on the documentation I found a CURL method to post files but seems like command line [OwnCloud Documentation](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.1/user_manual/files/access_webdav.html#accessing-files-using-curl) so if anyone know how to parse ir or use it on php will be a great help for my objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally to manage my files through owncloud I had to point the form to a directorory on the webserver and then used the owncloud plugin to mount external storage sources and works pretty fine to me.

[External Storage Configuration](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual/configuration_files/external_storage_configuration_gui.html)

Comment: Any example? I'm also stuck

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your curl options:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: Basic');
```

or to use your existing convention:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Authorization: Basic');
```

Comment: It works but now the server responses :  Sabre\DAV\Exception\Conflict PUT is not allowed on non-files.

Comment: Investigating about using post on owncloud I found isn't a supported method :(

Comment: @NMenam Can you post the working code to upload large files to owncloud in php form?is the above code is working?

Comment: I've just created a simple form to upload files to server and then I've mounted the server folder with the external storage from owncloud, sadly I don't have the code :(

Answer (score 0):

To upload file to owncloud with html form and php

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Theform is here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div align="center">
                <h1> File uploads with OwnCloud API</h1>
                <form method="post" action="" name="fileuploader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label>Select a File to upload</label><br>
                    <input type="file" name="file"></input><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload file"></input>
                </form>
                <?php
                ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>


$file_path_str = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/' . basename($filename));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);

$fh_res = fopen($file_path_str, 'r');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path_str));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE); // --data-binary

$curl_response_res = curl_exec ($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    print_r($error_msg);exit;
}
fclose($fh_res);
```